# getting data from previous activity error

Tags: android

i am having problem with my code i am sending a data from one activity to another.
i dont know what is the problem here, ive got a lot of error in my logcat. i am new to android. thanks!

Here's my code for the sender activity

```
public void sendFeedback(View button) {

          EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
          String name1 = name.getText().toString();

        //Create new Intent Object, and specify class
          Intent intent = new Intent();  
          intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,result.class);

          //Set your data using putExtra method which take 
          //any key and value which we want to send 
          intent.putExtra("senddata",name1);  

          //Use startActivity or startActivityForResult for Starting New Activity
          MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent); 

         }
}
```

and this is the code for the receiver activity:

```
TextView name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    {
    //obtain  Intent Object send  from SenderActivity
      Intent intent = this.getIntent();

      /* Obtain String from Intent  */
      if(intent !=null)
      {
         String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("senddata");
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
         name2.setText(strdata);
      }
      else
      {
       // DO SOMETHING HERE
      } 
}
```

and this is my logcat:

```
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{dev.msg.feedbackmessaging/dev.msg.feedbackmessaging.result}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at dev.msg.feedbackmessaging.result.<init>(result.java:17)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-17 02:02:52.576: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
```

thanks guys.

Comment: What is at result.java:17 ? Seems You're trying to call findViewById befor onCreate() call.

Comment: Do you have both activities in the manifest?  I occassionally forget to add them and always get a confusing error message in logcat.

Comment: Your initialization fails. Shows us the whole activity code

Comment: getIntent().getExtras().getString("senddata"); try this one.

Comment: you better show the whole code, exception may not be related to getIndent"().getExtras().getString()

Answer (score 0):

I think when you set the value  intent.putExtra("senddata",name1);  then name1 is null and

```
String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("senddata");
```

here u are not using any default value

you should getString with default vaule like

```
String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("senddata","");
```

it may remove your exception.